# Is Ubuntu Studio dead?

Tags: ubuntu-studio

What the plans for Ubuntu Studio?

I see 11.10 is the lastest release and it is transitioning to XFCE with no plans to utilize Unity.

The [recommended release is 10.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/10.04/release/) according to the wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UbuntuStudio is actively being maintained - the UbuntuStudio team are currently preparing for their 12.04 release (at the time of writing this, [beta 2 is available](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/12.04/beta-2/) for download).

If you look at the [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-studio-devel/2012-April/thread.html) - they are actively tracking and fixing bugs.

They have just [announced](http://dream.dickmacinnis.com/forum/node/775) a new Art Lead - Dick MacInnis

[UbuntuStudio 12.04](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/UbuntuStudio/12.04/LTS-Proposal) is going to be a LTS release and will include new and updated packages (see the link for details).

- Ubuntu Studio 12.04.1: 19 July 2012
- Ubuntu Studio 12.04.2: 31 January 2013
- Ubuntu Studio 12.04.3: 15 August 2013
- Ubuntu Studio 12.04.4: 24 January 2014

Comment: Guess the Ubuntu Studio wiki needs updating *BADLY*

Comment: I'm sure they are looking for volunteers... apply through the dev mailing list!

Comment: maybe I'll throw in.

Answer (score 2):

No, it appears it is not dead yet but it could use an active maintainer. See the launchpad answers post for more information. Someone needs to update their wiki. However, they are planning to use XFCE because it is lighter weight and some prefer it over Unity.

Source: [Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/5269)

Comment: The last query was in 4-20-2007 so it appears to have died

Comment: Thats just for the launchpad question.

Comment: Yeah, I know...